# Can't retrieve data from associated model

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a User model and a Profile model.

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const UserSchema = new Schema({
  name: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  email: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  password: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  }
});

module.exports = User = mongoose.model('users', UserSchema);

const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const ProfileSchema = new Schema({
  user: {
    type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: 'users'
  },
  handle: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  bio: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  location: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  }
});

module.exports = Profile = mongoose.model('profile', ProfileSchema);
```

I'm trying to retrieve the user name and email inside of the following route:

```
router.get('/', passport.authenticate('jwt', { session: false} ), (req, res) => {
  console.log(req.user);
  Profile.findOne({ user: req.user.id })
    .populate('user', ['name', 'email'])
    .then(profile => {
      if (!profile) {
        return res.status(404).json({error: 'Profile not found!'})
      }

      res.json(profile);
    })
    .catch(err => res.status(404).json(err));
});
```

I keep getting back 'Profile not found' even though the user exists in my database. I also know that the id is being passed along because console.log(req.user) logs the following:

```
[0] Listening on port 8080!
[0] MongoDB connected
[0] { _id: 5afcab77c4b9a9030eee35a7,
[0]   name: 'Harry',
[0]   email: 'harry@gmail.com',
[0]   password: '$2a$10$vOkK/Mpx04cR06Pon0t.2u5iKqGXetGuajKTZyBvLNWwgPjN6RO3q',
[0]   __v: 0 }
```

Passing req.user.id to Profile.findOne should retrieve the profile and the associated users name and email but I can't get anything back. Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

This is the Profile document as it appears in the database:

```
{
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "5b0715288ae56b028b442e7b"
    },
    "handle": "johndoe",
    "bio": "Hi, my name is John and I live in Toronto, ON, Canada!",
    "location": "Toronto, ON",
    "__v": 0
}
```

Comment: You're showing us the "User" document. What about the "Profile" you are trying to match on. Show that document. Or did you just think that mongoose created the "link" for you? Your query is  looking at the `"user"` property of the "Profile"` model. It probably does not exist and therefore no result is returned. Or you managed to save it previously as a "string".

Comment: The 'User' and 'Profile' documents are shown above in the first code snippet. There is a 'user' property on the 'Profile' model. My understanding is that by specifying 'user.type' as an object id and 'user.ref' as the referenced collection should create the link for me.

Comment: Those are "schema: . You need to be showing the "document" as it appears in the "collection" in the "database". And your understanding is incorrect as references are not "created for you" and you need to record the referenced information yourself. It certainly appears like you have misunderstood, but showing the actual "document content" will make it clear

Comment: I have copied and pasted the Profile document as it appears in the mLab database. It's at the bottom of the original post. Hope that helps.